# Not reaching Gigabit (~30MB/s) with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

I have a dual boot setup (Windows 7/Ubuntu 14.04) on my Samsung Laptop Np530U3C.

When booting into Windows, I get around 80-90 MB/s (read and write) via wired network transfer to my desktop machine (Windows 8.1). That's totally fine, the rest is protocol overhead I'd guess.

Unfortunately, when booting into Ubuntu, I can't reach more than ~30 MB/s. Considering the setup is the same all the time, the issue has to lie within Ubuntu.

What can I do to get somewhere near gigabit?

Comment: What protocol are you using to transfer these files and what is the latency between you and the server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mentioned what protocol you are using to transfer files. Regardless, one thing you could check is that your connection is negotiating properly:

```
ethtool eth0
```

Replace eth0 with whatever your actual interface is. You're looking for the rate and duplex parameters - they should be negotiating at 1000Mb/s, Full. If they aren't, then you can try setting them manually:

```
ethtool -s eth0 autoneg off speed 1000 duplex full
```

Comment: Alright, i just chekced its on 1000MB/s and full. Which must ahev anyway, otherwise i'd only get ~12,5MB/s, right?

Comment: Yes, I was reading MB and thinking 'Mb'. Sorry :( If it was negotiating at 100Mb/s then you'd be seeing about 11.5 MB/s (~90Mb/s) max, assuming you had resolved whatever is causing this reduction in throughput.